# Flutter : google map dont show

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have flutter app using google map, I created project and api key in google cloud,and enabled for both Andriod and iOS.

I add these permisions to AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

also ad Api Key to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:label="xxxx"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            .............
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

then I used getlocator package to get location in provider for showing the map :

```
GoogleMap(
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(authProvider.latitudePosition,
                                      authProvider.longitudePosition),
                  zoom: 14))
```

nothing to show on emulator (the emulator using google play) also I get this :
 `updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.`

Comment: Was that  added in android/app/AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Comment: @HardikMehta add to android/app/Src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: is the API key restricted? you need to make sure that the API key is authorized